# Recovering from a bad Topology Manager Installation

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, topology-manager

We're working on an upgrade from 2013 SP1 HR1 to Web 8.5 but have run into an issue installing Topology Manager where the installation failed, but the installer is reporting Topology Manager as being installed - yet we don't see the IIS website or any of the PowerShell Modules.

[image]

Which seems straight forward enough. We feel confident that we can debug this connection issue, however because of the error at this step we think we're in a bit of a corrupted install state (Topology Manager only; everything else is fine).

Topology Manager still shows up in the list of installed features, but the IIS site and PowerShell modules are not available. Just wondering if anyone's run into this, and if so - how'd you solve it?

[image]

When we try to uninstall Topology Manager specifically via the installer, we're told we need to uninstall a bunch of dependent components beforehand. We're planning to run a repair on the install but failing that I wanted to see what options we have to fix the Topology Manager installation without having to uninstall the dependent features.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any words of wisdom!

Answer (score 1):

Try this following steps to fix this.

1. Either remove TM DB and recreate the new DB using the install script
2. or Remove all of the configurations in the SDL Web Topology Manager by running the following PowerShell commands.

   ```
   (Get-TtmMapping).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmMapping -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmWebApplication).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmWebApplication -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmWebsite).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmWebsite -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmCdTopology).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmCdTopology -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmCdEnvironment).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmCdEnvironment -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmCmEnvironment).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmCmEnvironment -Id $_ }
   (Get-TtmCdTopologyType).Id | ForEach { Remove-TtmCdTopologyType -Id $_ }
   ```
3. Try to remove the Content Manager ID stored in the System Environment Variable `TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID`
4. Re-install the Topology Manager using the installer

I hope this helps.

Comment: While this helps us wipe the Topology Manager environment specific data, it doesn't answer my question. I'm asking how we can complete the 4th step you listed because the Content Manager is telling us Topology Manager is already installed, but crucial components are missing when we try to reinstall it. We can't uninstall TM by itself (see original post) so we're left in a weird state.

Comment: yeah. I can see your original connection error seems not able to connect core service on the server - may be some other services uses that port. Is there any specific reason you don't want to remove the dependencies components while uninstalling TM?

Comment: Not particular Velmurugan - we were curious why we'd need to uninstall those modules as they don't really seem dependent. We were able to install TM ontop of those modules, so why is TM now dependent on them? No worries! We uninstalled those modules first and everything went through okay. Thanks for the help.